# Django-material : from material.forms ImportError: No module named forms

Tags: django, django-forms, django-1.10

I'm trying to test an apps that use material.forms but i got this error:-

```
from material.forms import ModelForm, InlineFormSetField
ImportError: No module named forms

i'm using virtualenv. 
python 2.7, 
django 1.10.5, 
django-material 0.12.5
```

Did i miss something?

Comment: I assume you're using `virtualenv`. Check if you have material-forms properly installed by typing `pip freeze`.  Check if the `python`, `django` and `material-forms` versions are compatible. Also tell us the steps you've performed so far

Comment: @Nrzonline yes i'm using virtualenv. I'm using python 2.7, django 1.10.5 and django-material 0.12.5

Comment: have you tried `material.forms.Form` ?

Comment: I've got the answer. I need to install django-material-pro.. thank you guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source code on [GitHub](https://github.com/viewflow/django-material/tree/master/material), there is no `material.forms`. I think you are supposed to use the normal Django`s `from django.forms import ModelForm, ..` and the package handles it front-end wise.

Comment: http://docs.viewflow.io/forms_formsets.html#material.forms.InlineFormSetField there seems to be `material.forms in the documentation.

Comment: Yes, it obviously does. But the `django-material 0.12.5` version he's using simply does not have `material.forms`. So the guide he's using is probably outdated.

Comment: Yea just  checked that, so it's definitely an issue with the versions he is using.

Comment: @BernardParah I've got the answer. I need to install django-material-pro.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://docs.viewflow.io/index.html) states that `django-viewflow requires Python 3.4 or greater, django 1.8/1.9/1.10:` whereas your python version is 2.7.

To use 2.7 you need to get the pro version. Read the docs for more info.

Comment: Yes i'm using the pro version

Comment: How about trying an explicit import then. `import material.forms.InlineFormSetField`